# How to dynamically call property names in C++ like square bracket notation in JS?

Tags: javascript, c++, square-bracket

My first language is Javascript, but I'm starting to learn C++. One of my favorite things to do is access properties with clever variable property names using square bracket notation in Javascript like so:

```
var a = "prop";
var obj = {
  this.prop : "before"
};
function alterObj(a){
  obj[a] = "after";
}
```

It doesn't seem to be coming up in my C++ books, and I'm having trouble Googling it. So how does one dynamically select property names in C++?

Comment: Square bracket with arrays, or objects. With javascript they are one and the same because arrays ARE objects, but that's not the case in many other languages.

Comment: @KevinB I think you missed the question. Square-Bracket notation is like: `obj[method | property]`. In other languages Dot-notation is most often used in my experience `obj.method`. In which can also be used in JavaScript.

Comment: I wasn't sure if he was asking about `arr[0]` or if he's asking about `obj["toString"]()`. Both are bracket notation

Comment: Since JS specific is mentioned. `arr[0]` is almost used standardly through many languages, not just in JavaScript.

Comment: I totally reworded my question with example code and a specific focus.

Comment: The question is much clearer. The answer is no. You cannot call property names like that in C++. Instead you use the "." or "->" operator (depending on if you have a pointer or not).

Comment: Part of what makes C++ so much faster than JavaScript is that it doesn't allow you do do stuff like this (though of course, you can use maps to achieve it where it's really necessary), but the normal structs and classes have their member names converted to byte-offsets at compile-time, so the information simply isn't available at runtime. This also gives you strict type checking, catching more bugs at compile-time. In short: you'll have to learn to write with more discipline if you want to get further in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is one cannot do this in c++. A major difference between c++ and javascript are that c++ is a compiled language whereas javascript is not. Javascript has a lot of neat runtime features that you can use, i.e. you can use bracket notation to access properties

```
obj["property"]
```

This allows any sort of string to be placed in the brackets and then evaluated at runtime. C++, however does not have as large of a runtime (there is a very powerful runtime, but powerful in a different way).

Now with all this said if you wanted to implement a function like your `alterObj` above you could use the `map` class. Also you can overload the `[]` operator. The following snippet gives an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class SpecialObject {
  public:
  std::string operator[](std::string key);
};

std::string SpecialObject::operator[](std::string key) {
  std::string retVal = key + " whoa!";
  return retVal;
}

void modify(std::map<std::string, std::string> &obj) {
  obj["something"] = "someone else";
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  std::map<std::string, std::string> obj;
  obj["something"] = "someone";
  modify(obj);
  std::cout << "obj[\"something\"] = " << obj["something"] << std::endl;

  SpecialObject obj2;
  std::cout << "obj2[\"The clowns say\"] = " << obj2["The clowns say"] << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The `map` object allows you to create a simple container for other objects (in some sense exactly like what javascript objects are) and the `SpecialObject` class shows how you can implement the `[]` operator yourself.

Answer (score 1):

C++ is a compiled language. Most names of classes, variables, properties, enums and functions don't make it to the final binary, they are processed in compile time and translated into memory offsets to the final [machine code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code) to use.

Such named references are almost completely lost and can only be backtraced with debug data.

Long story short, there is no way you can do this in C or C++. But you can still work with pointers or use preprocessor macros.